# Is it possible to get SMS like bubble in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is it possible to get SMS like bubble in iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use a UIImageView containing a stretchable image of the sms bubble as the background for your view.

[This article](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=358) explains the technique and is exactly what you are after.